# Spring Boot tries to connect to Mongo localhost

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have a Spring Boot 2.x project using Mongo.  I am running this via Docker (using compose locally) and Kubernetes.  I am trying to connect my service to a Mongo server.  This is confusing to me, but for development I am using a local instance of Mongo, but deployed in GCP I have named mongo services.

here is my application.properties file:

```
#mongodb
spring.data.mongodb.uri= mongodb://mongo-serviceone:27017/serviceone

#logging
logging.level.org.springframework.data=trace
logging.level.=trace
```

And my Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

# Define the services/containers to be run
services:
  service: #name of your service
    build: ./ # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3009:3009" #specify ports forwarding
    links:
      - mongo-serviceone # link this service to the database service
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - mongo-serviceone

  mongo-serviceone: # name of the service
    image: mongo
    volumes:
        - ./data:/data/db
    ports:
        - "27017:27017"
```

When I try docker-compose up . I get the following error:

> mongo-serviceone_1          | 2018-08-22T13:50:33.454+0000 I NETWORK
>   [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017 service_1
>   | 2018-08-22 13:50:33.526  INFO 1 --- [localhost:27017]
>   org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread
>   while connecting to server localhost:27017 service_1
>   |  service_1                   | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException:
>   Exception opening socket service_1                   |   at
>   com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62)
>   ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.3.jar!/:na]

running `docker ps` shows me:

```
692ebb72cf30        serviceone_service        "java -Djava.securit…"   About an hour ago   Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:3009->3009/tcp, 8080/tcp   serviceone_service_1
6cd55ae7bb77        mongo                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp           serviceone_mongo-serviceone_1
```

While I am trying to connect to a local mongo, I thought that by using the name "mongo-serviceone"

Comment: The startup message looks to me like MongoDB is configured to listen on `localhost`; it should listen on `0.0.0.0` or it won't be reachable outside its container.  I don't know the appropriate configuration change though.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell what the exact issue is, but maybe this is just an issue because of the space " " after "spring.data.mongodb.uri=" and before "mongodb://mongo-serviceone:27017/serviceone"?

If not, maybe exec into the "service" container and try to ping the mongodb with: `ping mongo-serviceone:27017`

Let me know the output of this, so I can help you analyze and fix this issue.

Alternatively, you could switch from using docker compose to a Kubernetes native dev tool, as you are planning to run your application on Kubernetes anyways. Here is a list of possible tools:

Allow hot reloading:

- **DevSpace:** https://github.com/covexo/devspace
- **ksync:** https://github.com/vapor-ware/ksync

Pure CI/CD tools for dev:

- **Skaffold:** https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold
- **Draft:** https://github.com/Azure/draft

For most of them, you will only need minikube or a dev namespace inside your existing cluster on GCP.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like another application was running on port 27017 on your localhost [Similar reported issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2161)

quick way to check on linux/mac:

```
telnet 127.0.01 27017
```

check logs files:

[docker logs serviceone_service](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)

Comment: I get the same logs inside my server:  Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
so I have a mongo process running locally (verified via top and mongo) but for whatever reason the connection seems rejected.  I think its just a standard mongo install on os x